# Android AOSP how to incl/excl modules from specific build

Tags: android, android-source

I downloaded AOSP source for Pixel XL (android-8.0.0_r3), the build is ok with `lunch aosp_marlin-userdebug`.

I understand that Pixel XL is using NFC chipset PN54X found in `system/nfc/halimpl/pn54x`. What bother me is under `system/nfc/halimpl` there are `bcm2079X` and `pn54x` 2 different modules, where in the source instruct pn54x's Android.mk being included in `aosp_marlin-userdebug` build but not `bcm2079X`? If I wanted to drop `pn54x` from the build and include `bcm2079X` how can I do so?

---

If you look closely at `system/nfc/Android.bp`, you will find `halimpl/bcm2079x/nfc_nci.c` is included. However, there is also a `nfc_nci.c` in `pn54x`. When I try injecting error into each file then build, I notice `halimpl/bcm2079x/nfc_nci.c` no error is reported, means the file is actually ignored by build. But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in `AOSP\device\google\marlin\device-marlin.mk` the nfc module is included in the .mk file:

```
# NFC packages
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    nfc_nci.marlin
```

The module name has to follow what found in `AOSP\src\system\nfc\halimpl\pn54x\Android.mk` ([android.mk](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk)):

```
LOCAL_MODULE := nfc_nci.$(TARGET_DEVICE)
```

To remove or add a nfc module, you will have to modify the device-marlin.mk accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Update: You are able to add or remove modules in the [device/](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/device/) directory. You can try to add the module somewhere in [/device/generic/x86_64/mini_x86_64.mk](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/device/generic/x86_64/mini_x86_64.mk) or [/device/generic/armv7-a-neon/mini_common.mk](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/device/generic/armv7-a-neon/mini_common.mk) (make sure you choose the correct lunch). You can even create your own device and create a `device.mk` with all modules, which are required for building.

The `bcm2079x` module is not ignored, it is included in [system/nfc/Android.bp](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/system/nfc/Android.bp) file directly.

To exclude the `pn54x` module you can rename/remove an `Android.mk` file and see what happens.

If you want to make your own command to build a **specific** AOSP with different modules like, e.g. `lunch aosp_marlin_custom-userdebug`, you need to add your own device. You can find how to do it [here.](https://source.android.com/source/add-device)

<sup>I'd rather post this as a comment, but I'm not able to.</sup>

Comment: Im not sure that is completely true. If you look closely at `system/nfc/Android.bp`, you will find `halimpl/bcm2079x/nfc_nci.c` is included. However, there is also a nfc_nci.c in pn54x. When I try injecting error into each file then build, I notice `halimpl/bcm2079x/nfc_nci.c` no error is reported, means the file is actually ignored by build. Any idea?

Comment: Do you build by `mm -B`/`mma` or you try to perform full rebuild? And how exactly did you try to inject an error?
Will you see any errors if you move all the files from `bcm2079x`?
Maybe, you won't receive any build errors, but these errors will be shown only while using files.

Comment: I have figured out the flow, check my answer